# No WiFi upon reboot - how can I run a command on reboot that restarts the service, or otherwse fix it?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, network-manager, reboot

When I restart my computer there is no WiFi connection. When I click on the WiFi symbol in the upper right corner and remove the tick at Activate Network and the set it again afterwards, it solves my problem and connects to my WiFi network automatically.

Is there a way to set a command which does exactly this after every reboot so that I do not have to click on it manually every time?
I am also open to other solutions. However, my deactivating and activating the network apparently solves the issue.

Output of `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` is the same for working/not working state:

```
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Output for `lsmod` when not working:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723be             135168  0
btcoexist             180224  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi               102400  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
wl                   6365184  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
kvm_amd                65536  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4  snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_amd
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
btusb                  45056  0
videodev              176128  4  uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
aesni_intel           167936  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
cfg80211              565248  3 wl,mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
edac_core              53248  0
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
k10temp                16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
fam15h_power           16384  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
pata_acpi              16384  0
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
amdkfd                131072  2
radeon               1515520  64
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu                987136  1
psmouse               131072  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
pata_atiixp            16384  0
ttm                    94208  2 amdgpu,radeon
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm_kms_helper        155648  2 amdgpu,radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  8 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  0
fjes                   28672  0
```

Output for `lsmod` after deactivating and re-activating network (i.e. when everything's working again):

```
Module                  Size  Used by
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
arc4                   16384  2
rtl8723be             135168  0
btcoexist             180224  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi               102400  3 btcoexist,rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
wl                   6365184  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
kvm_amd                65536  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
kvm                   540672  1 kvm_amd
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
btusb                  45056  0
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
aesni_intel           167936  4
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
btintel                16384  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
cfg80211              565248  3 wl,mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
edac_core              53248  0
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
k10temp                16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
fam15h_power           16384  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
pata_acpi              16384  0
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
amdkfd                131072  2
radeon               1515520  65
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu                987136  1
psmouse               131072  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
pata_atiixp            16384  0
ttm                    94208  2 amdgpu,radeon
ahci                   36864  3
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm_kms_helper        155648  2 amdgpu,radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  9 ttm,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,radeon
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  0
fjes                   28672  0
```

`rfkill list all` returns in both states:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is the same for working/not working state:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

Comment: And the comparison of `lsmod` when working/not working.

Comment: I added the outputs in the question.

Comment: What about `rfkill list all` results?

Comment: I just included the output for `rfkill list all` in the question.

Comment: Could you add the content of `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` ?

Comment: I just added the content @kcdtv

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that solves the problem. The command `sudo service NetworkManager restart` did the trick. Since copying this into a startup-application would not be a very good solution due to the password needed, I instead added `service NetworkManager restart` to the file `etc/rc.local` (So the above code without the `sudo`) This file automatically executes at startup.
To do this I used `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`. So far, I haven't had any more connection problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, as *workaround* you can try to use `TLP` in order to start Wi-Fi automatically on start-up.

However I think this could be an *issue* with your BIOS/EFI settings. Try to investigate into it.

Comment: Which settings would I have to check specifically?

Comment: The state of wireless devices when boot & the switch key/s behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use **Ubuntu 16.10** as no flavor and version is mentionned. The *restart* of the wifi connexion is done every time you *login* into your desktop. This is not exactly what you specify but should do the trick.

First, check what is the current active connection with

```
nmcli con show --active
```

Take note of the uuid

Then, create a file in `~/.config/autostart`, for example `~/.config/autostart/restartwifi.desktop` with content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Restart wifi connection
GenericName=Network helper
Comment=Restart automatically wifi connection
Exec=/home/YukiJ/bin/restartwifi.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=Terminal
Categories=Network;
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Then create a shell script that will shutdown and restart the said above active current connexion.
For example, in `~/bin` (else change the filename path in desktop file above) as `~/bin/restartwifi.sh`

```
#/bin/bash
UUID="<theuuid>" # to be replaced with the acual uuid without < and >
sleep 3
nmcli con down $UUID
sleep 2
exec nmcli con up $UUID
```

Comment: I use 16.04, sorry.
This solution, unfortunately, did not help. I still don't find WiFi networks until I deactivate the network in the upper right corner and activate it again.

Comment: Then It's NetworkManager that you need to restart automatically.

Comment: Which changes would I then have to make in the two files created above?

Comment: The command `sudo service NetworkManager restart` solves the problem. Is there any way to run it automatically after booting without entering the password every time?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear which bit of your stack is failing but one of the three options below should allow you to work around it.

You could use networkmanager to restart the wifi

```
nmcli radio wifi off
sleep 2
nmcli radio wifi on
```

You could use systemd to restart networkmanager

```
systemctl restart networking.service
```

You could reload the wifi module , mine is intel yours may vary

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sleep 2
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. When my Ubuntu 16.04 was loaded it never showed me available WiFi networks. I connected my laptop via Ethernet  cable and in the terminal I run: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

Then just `sudo reboot` and it is working until now without a problem. Maybe it is a simple solution for your problem?

`bcwml-kernel-source`stands for my Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source. What is your NIC card model?